# ReferenceError: apiUrl is not defined when fetching data from InfluxDB using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, database

I have created an influxDB container on my raspbarry PI. Now Im trying to write an Website where i can show the data that is in my database on my Website. I have created a JavaScript library to fech data from my database and display it on my website. Im using the fetch API to send an HTTP request to the InfluxDB API and retrieve the data. However, Im getting this when i refresh my website:

```
ReferenceError: apiUrl is not defined
    datenAbrufen file:///C:/Users/Amir/Desktop/Projekt/index.html:102
    abrufenUndAnzeigen file:///C:/Users/Amir/Desktop/Projekt/index.html:135
    <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/Amir/Desktop/Projekt/index.html:140
```

Why am I getting this and how can I resolve the issue.

```
class InfluxDBLibrary {

    // Klassen konstruktor
    constructor(optionen){
        this.host = optionen.host;
        this.port = optionen.port;
        this.datenbank = optionen.datenbank;
    }
    
    async datenAbrufen(abfrage){
        // Methode zum Abrufen von Daten aus der Datenbank
        const url = 'http://${this.host}:${this.port}/abfrage?db=${encodeURIComponent(this.datenbank)}&q=${encodeURIComponent(abfrage)}';
        
        // Der API-URL wird basierend auuf den Host, Port und Datenbankname erstellt
        const antwort = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'       
            }
        });
    
        // Hier wird eine HTTP-GET Anfrage an die Datenbank geschickt und der Datenbank soll eine Antwort zurück schicken
        if(!antwort.ok){
            
            // Wenn die Antwort nicht erfolgreich ist, soll eine Fehler meldung mit der entsprechende Fehlermeldungm, ausgegeben werden
            throw new Error('Abrufen der Daten, Fehlgeschlagen:${antwort.statusText}');
        }
    
        // Die Antwort von Server, wird in eine JavaScript-Objekt interpretiert
        const daten = await antwort.json();
        return daten;
        
        }
    }
```

```
            // Hier wird die Verbindung zur Datenbank definiert
            const optionen = {
                host: 'Pi_IP',
                port: '8087',
                datenbank: 'Web_Test'
            };

            const influxDB = new InfluxDBLibrary(optionen)

            // Hier werde die Daten abgerufen und in HTML-Seite angezeigt
            async function abrufenUndAnzeigen(){
                const abfrage = 'select Temperatur from test';
                const daten = await influxDB.datenAbrufen(abfrage);
                const datenAnzeigenElement = document.getElementById('Temperatur');
                datenAnzeigenElement.innerText = JSON.stringify(daten);
            }

            abrufenUndAnzeigen().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I don't see where that variable is being referenced in the code.  The stack trace points to line 102, which line is that?